# Is there a name for these subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition, combinatorial-group-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Let $F$ be a free group. Let $F_1$ be a subgroup with basis $B$.   Assume that $F_1$ has the property that for every $\alpha\in F-F_1$, the set $\{\alpha\}\cup B$ is still free.

Is there a name for such subgroup $F_1$ with this property? Or are there known characterizations of these subgroups? We might restrict both the rank of $F$ and $F_1$ to be finite.

Comment: Partly a guess: is this not equivalent to being malnormal? ($F^g\cap F\neq1\Rightarrow g\in H$) Certainly such a subgroup is malnormal.

Comment: I don't know if it's equivalent to being malnormal.

Comment: Me neither. It just looked like a nice characterisation, if it were true :-)

Comment: It turns out the two properties are not equivalent. One example is to consider $C$ in $F=\langle a,b;\rangle$ generated by $a^{-1}b$ and $a^2b^2$. It can be shown that $C$ is malnormal, and we have $a\not\in C$ but $a^2(aa^{-1}b)^2(a^2b^2)^{-1}=1$.